# Is there any way to check object's key value on entire array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am finding a way to check object key's value is empty or not in entire array, actually I am receiving lengthy array from an API which length is more than 1500 so I do not want run map function, or loop because array is too lengthy.

here is screenshot.

[image]

and here is an example of response what i get from API

```js
[{
    reference: "1234",
    address: "abcz",
    city: "sydney",
    conso: "",
    date: "26/04/2017"
  },
  {
    reference: "1234",
    address: "abcz",
    city: "sydney",
    conso: "",
    date: "26/04/2017"
  },
  {
    reference: "1234",
    address: "abcz",
    city: "sydney",
    conso: "",
    date: "26/04/2017"
  },
  {
    reference: "1234",
    address: "abcz",
    city: "sydney",
    conso: "",
    date: "26/04/2017"
  },
  ....

]
```

Comment: You could store the results into a database and then execute SQL queries.

Comment: what do you want to check? Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: `var exists = JSON.stringify(arr).indexOf("1234")!=-1;`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some – you *will* have to loop through the array, there's no way to magically do it without looking at each item.

Comment: 1500 isn't all that many - have you tried it to see if there is an actual performance issue?

Comment: @deceze - is that not a map under the hood?

Comment: @mplungjan Well, no, it's a short-circuiting loop. That's the best you can do.

Comment: @JamesThorpe actually it depend on client how much they want to get and show their report so sometime response is more than 3000. I mentioned minimum length.

Comment: Well, benchmark how long it takes to `.some`/`.map` an array of 3000 items… probably not as long as you think.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which exits on the first find.

```
var allEmpty = data.some(o => o[key] !== '');
```

or check for all, then use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
var allEmpty = data.every(o => o[key] === '');
```

Comment: I believe what you want in your first example is really `let someHaveData = data.some(o => o[key] !== '')`.

Comment: @deceze, it's a bit unlcear, if not empty, a single empty or all empty check is required.

Comment: I would guess the OP wants to hide the entire column if no data in it exists, so a "has some data" check probably makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear from your question exactly what you want. If you only want to see if one object in the array has an empty 'conso' property then this will work without having to necessarily search through the whole array:

```
const emptyConso = arr.find(place => !place.conso)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite slow alas

```
var ref = "1499"
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj).indexOf('"reference":"'+ref+'"')!=-1);
```

compared to

```
console.log(obj.some(o => o["reference"] === ref))
```

https://jsperf.com/some-or-stringify/